# Laravel 4: Get specific field using Eloquent ORM Model

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm very new to Laravel, having a database like this:

```
code  |     descriptor    |    id
_______________________________________
frd     Ford                1
chv     Chevrolet           2
fer     Ferrari             3
```

Model:

```
class Car extends Eloquent {}
```

How do I query using the `code` to get the `descriptor`?

Like this:
`SELECT descriptor FROM car WHERE code = 'fer'`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in laravel's [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) you can use where with models

```
$cars= Car::where('code', '=', 'fer')->get();
```

And second paramater is not obligatory if it is '='

```
$cars= Car::where('code', 'fer')->get();
```

**Edit:**

If you just want an array of a single column you can use [this](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects)

```
$cars= DB::table('cars')->where('code', 'fer')->lists('id');
```

Comment: how do i get the `id` field only?

Comment: instead of ```->get``` use ```->select('id')``` but that's on queries